# How to use local variable in spock test case in another class?

Tags: variables, groovy

I want to use the "dashVer" in StartupTest.groovy in Zip.groovy, but "dashVer" in Zip.groovy return in "null". For detail, please read below, thank you very much!!!!

StartupTest.groovy

```
class StartupTest extends Specification {

String dashVer

void updateGlobalString(String dashVersion){
    dashVer=dashVersion
}

def 'Start_test'() {
    setup:
    .......

    when: 'Test started'
    String dashVersion= new GetDashVer().Get_dash_ver().toString()
    println(dashVersion) //Eg.the result is 3.3.3 return from GetDashVer class sucessfully
    updateGlobalString(dashVersion)

    and:
    ...

    then:
    ...

}
}
```

Zip.groovy

```
class ZipUploadSlack {

//Attempt 1
StartupTest test = new StartupTest()
String dashVer111 = test.updateGlobalString()

//Attept 2
//StartupTest test = new StartupTest()
//String dashVer111 = test.dashVer

 def 'Zip'(){

    println(dashVer111) //This should be return in 3.3.3, but it is "null" for now for both attepts
}
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a value in a test in another class?!

Comment: Because I want to separate the zip, upload and send notice tasks in the "ZipUploadSlack" class from the test case, then I can only call the function at the end of the test by one line. Let the test case itself look cleaner. 


I tried to put those task below "clean up:" in the test case, it works. But once I seperate to different class, the version return to null instead of the version.

Comment: I understand your decire to split into multiple classes, but Spock does not guarantee any specific order your tests are being run in (and you infer a bad practice of dependencies between test classes). Consider inheritance from the same super class at least. 
In your code, updateGlobalString() is called without an argument, setting dashVer to null, and returning only the result of an assignment of null to the value. This I would also expect return null. Have you considered making the  dashVer variable static, so it is shared across classes instead.

Answer (score 0):

@Jacob Aae Mikkelsen, thanks for the advice. Seems static variable working. 
Just tried with below:

Startuptest.groovy

```
class StartupTest extends Specification {

static String dashbVer
static Integer errorCount

String updateGlobalString(String dashVersion){
    dashVer=dashVersion
    return dashVer
}

Integer updateGlobalInteger(Integer errorC){
    errorCount=errorC
    return errorCount
}

void updateGlobalString(String dashVersion){
dashVer=dashVersion
}

def 'Start_test'() {
setup:
.......

when: 'Test started'
String dashVersion= new GetDashVer().Get_dash_ver().toString()
println(dashVersion) //Eg.the result is 3.3.3 return from GetDashVer class sucessfully
updateGlobalString(dashVersion)

and:
...

then: 'No error log found'
def error = dash.logFinder.search(/\(ERROR\)/)
error.isEmpty() //Let says it is true, it is empty as no error found
int errorC = error.size() as Integer //.size is using List.java, @return the number of elements in this list

println(errorC) //Here return as 0 as expected
updateGlobalInteger(errorC) // Here return with error, "condition not satisfied groovy"

}
}
```

Zip.groovy

```
class ZipUploadSlack {
//Obtain dashVer
StartupTest test = new StartupTest()
String dashVer111 = test.dashVer

def 'Zip'(){
println(dashVer111) //This can return correct dashVer now
}
}
```

My new question is why there is "condition not satisfied groovy" error when executing updateGlobalInteger(errorC)? errorC is integer and the updateGlobalInteger function is returning a integer, why failed? Thanks!!!!